# SQL how to select from 2 tables and match them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called users and table called events.
Every user sets is own preferred "area codes".

Every event is set to some area codes, and this information is saved in a table:

```
events_areas:
area_id BIGINT
event_id BIGINT
```

**I am trying to find a good way to let the user select is own area codes... and then to match it in a select statement with the event area codes.**

i tought about doing the same as events_areas and do: users_areas:

```
area_id BIGINT
user_id BIGINT
```

But then I dont know how to match them in select statement... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tables you listed, the following would select all events in the users selected area codes.

```
SELECT u.*, e.*
FROM users u
JOIN users_areas ua
  ON u.id = ua.user_id
JOIN events_areas ea
  ON ea.area_id = ua.area_id
JOIN events e
  ON ea.event_id = e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The select statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*, events.*
FROM users
JOIN users_areas ON users.user_id = users_areas.user_id
JOIN events_areas ON users_areas.area_id = event_areas.area_id
JOIN events ON events_areas.event_id = events.event_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I changed this based on your comment...

Create these tables:

```
Table: user
id
name

Table: user_area
id
user_id
area_id

Table: event
id
name

Table: event_area
id
event_id
area_id

Table: area
id
area_code
```

Then run this query:

```
SELECT event.name FROM event, event_area WHERE event.id = event_area.event_id AND event_area.area_id IN (SELECT area_id FROM user_area WHERE user_id = <CURRENTUSERSID>)
```

Comment: Sorry i am trying to let each user select many area codes, and same for events... then for example if event got area codes: 1,3,4 and the user got are codes: 3,5,8- it matches

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to start listing the relations between the tables (objects) in plain English. For example:

1. A user belongs to an area code and an area code has many users.
2. An event happens in an area code and an area code has many events.

Both statements describe many-to-many relations, so you do need those two tables (sometimes called *cross-reference* tables).

Writing those statements always helps to understand the problem and ask questions about it. Assuming the statements above are correct, then having those two tables `users_areas` and `events_areas` is correct too. To build the `select` statement, note that there's only one column that both tables have in common: `area_id` (which by the way, would fit in a `int`, using `bigint` is a **huge** overkill, and I think the same goes for `user_id` and `event_id`). So `area_id` is the column you need to use to *match* them (the correct term is to *join* them).

Here's your select statement:

```
SELECT ea.event_id, ea.area_id, ua.user_id
FROM events_areas ea
    INNER JOIN user_areas ua ON ea.area_id = ua.area_id
```

Or, assuming you also have an `event` table and a `user` table, which is likely the case, we expand the `select` to look like this:

```
SELECT e.name, u.name
FROM events_areas ea
    INNER JOIN user_areas ua ON ea.area_id = ua.area_id
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
    INNER JOIN events e ON e.event_id = ue.event_id
```

Comment: I got your point about the understaing of the problem, thank you. and also you are right i will try your solution. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
    FROM users u
        INNER JOIN users_areas ua
            ON u.user_id = ua.user_id
        INNER JOIN events_areas ea
            ON ua.area_id = ea.area_id
        INNER JOIN events e
            ON ea.event_id = e.event_id
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?